# How to get port number for iPhone Chatting Application

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmpp4r

I am developing a chat application.

But Right now chatting is possible with only google because I know only google's port no.

```
xmppClient = [[XMPPClient alloc] init];
[xmppClient addDelegate:self];

// Replace me with the proper domain and port.
// The example below is setup for a typical google talk account.
[xmppClient setDomain:@"talk.google.com"];
[xmppClient setPort:5222];
```

You can see that, google has set 5222 as port number.

Same way I want to set port no for yahoo, windows messenger & other popular sites, How can I get all these?

(Is it something like that - "XMPP is specific for Google ones" ? ? )

Comment: This belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5222/tcp is the default port for XMPP, but your implementation may have a different one.  To find out, you do a [DNS SRV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) query for `_xmpp-client._tcp.YOURDOMAIN`, where you replace `YOURDOMAIN` with the domain you're trying to connect to.  This will return 0+ records that have hostname/port combinations for how to connect.  If you get 0 records back, assume port 5222.

For example, I want to connect to the GoogleTalk server, and log in with the account `foo@gmail.com`.  My client performs the lookup that can be simulated with dig on the command line like this:

```
% dig +short -t SRV _xmpp-client._tcp.gmail.com.
20 0 5222 talk1.l.google.com.
20 0 5222 talk4.l.google.com.
5 0 5222 talk.l.google.com.
20 0 5222 talk3.l.google.com.
20 0 5222 talk2.l.google.com.
```

The result with the lowest priority number is `5 0 5222 talk.l.google.com.`, which means you open a TCP connection to `talk.l.google.com` on port 5222.

To make SRV queries from code, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258284/srv-record-lookup-with-iphone-sdk/258799#258799), which relies on DNSServiceQueryRecord.

Answer (score 4):

[Kraken's Openfire Properties Page](http://kraken.blathersource.org/node/8) has the port and domain information you need. Just re-use and try with your application.

Answer (score 0):

> 5222 is the default port for XMPP, but
>   your implementation may have a
>   different one. To find out, you do a
>   DNS server query for
>   _xmpp-client._tcp.DOMAIN_Name, where you replace DOMAIN_Name with the
>   domain you're trying to connect to(ex.
>   gmail.com,google.com,yahoo.com). This
>   will return 0+ records that have
>   hostName/port combinations for how to
>   connect. If you get 0 records back,
>   assume port 5222.