# How to implement DNS query in iOS

Tags: ios, dns

I need some information including **host(target)**, **port**, **priority** etc.

like this: 
[SRV record lookup with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258284/srv-record-lookup-with-iphone-sdk)

but it's for `Mac OS X` not `iOS`

Any suggestion to help me?

2013/08/19
I'm found another library from Apple
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SRVResolver/Listings/Read_Me_About_SRVResolver_txt.html

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it in C and call it from ObjectiveC.

Here's an example I to get you started: https://gist.github.com/wil/6141275

Make sure you link with `-lresolv` (i.e. `libresolv.dylib`)

I wrote this for another question for resolving TXT records, but it should be fairly easy to extend it for SRV. Let me know if you need more info.